# Beginner can't clear some lines into this code for LCD Screen

Tags: python

Here is a part of code that screen some words on my LCD screen from a Raspberry Pi.

It's work fine but I can't clear all the screen between each groups of words. For the moment : new word is written while last words remains on the screen

CODE :

```
 def typewriter_like(sentence, lcd_line, delay=0.7):
     for i,letter in enumerate(sentence):
         lcd_byte(lcd_line, LCD_CMD)
         lcd_string(sentence[:i+1],1)
         time.sleep(delay)


  mots = (("EXAMPLE", "EXAMPLES", "EXAMPLESS", "EXAMPLESSS"),
          ("ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"),
          ("LULU", "FIFI", "LOLO", "RIRI"),
          ("NEW", "NEWW", "NEWWW", "NEWWWW"))
  lcds = (0x80, 0xC0, 0x94, 0xD4)
  list(zip(mots,lcds))
  [(('EXAMPLE', 'EXAMPLES', 'EXAMPLESS', 'EXAMPLESSS'),128),(('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR'),192),(('LULU', 'FIFI', 'LOLO', 'RIRI'),148),(("NEW", "NEWW", "NEWWW", "NEWWWW")),128]

  while True:
    for mot in mots:
        for word, lcd in zip(mot, lcds):
            typewriter_like(word, lcd)
        time.sleep(10)

    for word, lcd in zip(mot, lcds):
        typewriter_like(" " * 20, lcd)

    time.sleep(4)
```

Basically I want to clear all the screen each time 4 words have been printed and have stayed screened the 10 seconds.

What I want : 
EXAMPLE/EXAMPLES/EXAMPLESS/EXAMPLESSS : ok... 10 seconds... then : **all** cleared before next 4 words : ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR

Comment: Why -3 ? That doesn't help ! Just giving good or bad points...

Answer (score 0):

Every LCD display has it's own instructions/commands . Based on your previous questions i guess it is the [HD44780](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf), now if will follow the linked manual, you will find a list of instructions on page 24 .

My guess is that the following line will clear the LCD .

```
lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)
```

Comment: Thanks but where should I write that ? In order to clear the LCD display between each group of words ?

Comment: Please take some time to understand the code you are writing, you will get through it in the end . There is no fun writing the entire program for you and you will learn nothing from that.